# x64 CMPS instruction (Compare String Operands)

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, machine-code

This instruction is confusing, here's the description for the 64-bit version on page 558 of the intel x64 manual:

Compares quadword at address (R|E)SI with quadword at address (R|E)DI and sets the status flags accordingly

So which is it, RSI and RDI or ESI and EDI??  Is there a way to set it?

Comment: The usual way, with an address size override prefix.

Comment: Like REX.W?  The manual lists (R|E)SI and (R|E)DI for REX.W + A7...

Comment: The REX.W is what makes it compare qwords (so, without it, it's a `cmpsd`), it doesn't affect the address size though. It's the good old 67h prefix.

Comment: Which prefix is first, 0x67 or 0x66/REX.W?

Comment: REX is always the last prefix, 0x66 and/or 0x67 (and rep, lock, etc) go before it. The "prefixes that are not REX" don't have an order though, except that Intel says that "mandatory prefixes should come last (but before REX)", I don't know how important that is

Comment: What about CMPSB?  Does REX.W make it compare 64-bit addresses?  Does 0x67 make it compare 32-bit addresses?  What does CMPSB compare by default without any prefixes? (in 64-bit mode of course)

Comment: I'm actually not sure what would happen, it wouldn't make sense anyway.. it already uses 64bit addresses, that has nothing to do with REX.W. It can't be upgraded to compare qwords, because it's a byte instruction.. address size override of course makes it use 32bit addresses

Comment: Checkout this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746743/intel-x64-instructions-cmpsb-cmpsw-cmpsd-cmpsq/30747277#30747277  I'm not sure about any of it really

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft ML64.EXE, the syntax would be:

```
        cmpsq                  ;64 bit addressing mode
        cmpsq   [rsi],[rdi]    ;64 bit addressing mode
        cmpsq   [esi],[edi]    ;32 bit addressing mode override
                               ;which may be invalid addresses (seg fault)
```