# Intel x64 instructions CMPSB/CMPSW/CMPSD/CMPSQ

Tags: x86, 64-bit, machine-code

These instructions are on page 558 of the intel manual.  I get the general idea but I'm stuck on the exact encdoding of these instructions.  Here is what I understand, please correct me if I'm wrong.  This is all in 64-bit mode.

```
Opcode - Instruction: 
A6 - compare byte at address RSI with byte at address RDI
67 A6 - compare byte at address ESI with byte at address EDI

66 A7 - compare word at address RSI with word at address RDI
67 66 A7 - compare word at address ESI with word at address EDI

A7 - compare dword at address RSI with dword at address RDI
67 A7 - compare dword at address ESI with dword at address EDI

REX.W A7 - Compares quadword at address RSI with quadword at address RDI
67 REX.W A7 - Compares quadword at address ESI with quadword at address EDI
```

Comment: Can you give a link to manual

Comment: Sure, http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf

Comment: Can anyone remove the hold?  I editted the question and would like to put a bounty on it

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of what those instructions are for, one must realize that they help a programmer automatize string (in the meaning of consecutive memory elements) comparison so that three things are done

1. Comparison between two memory location, which can't be done with a single `cmp` instruction
2. Comparison affecting flags, so that you can check the result right in the next instruction, or just use the `rep`/`repnz` prefix to loop unless a certain condition is not met.
3. Incrementation/Decrementation of both source operands according to `DF`, which would otherwise have to be done by at least two `inc`/`dec` or `add`/`sub` instructions, with the latter required for operations on more that just one byte

You've also shown some interest in instruction encoding. In the first place, `cmpsx` instructions can be encoded in two ways - with or without specified operands. This may be particularly useful, although there are some limitations.

Other things are just playing with prefix bytes. Onto this just note, that you can override the segment of the first source operand using the segment override prefix, but you can't override the `es` as the segment of the second operand.

Comment: Yes the main question was about the encoding, did I get it right??  Thank you for the explanation though.

Comment: There is only one operand encoding: implicit. Anything else is an illusion at the assembly level.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, isn't there 8 different encodings at the machine code level?

Comment: I mean how do you differentiate between 64 and 32-bit addresses on say CMPSB?  The manual says you can do either.

Comment: @RyanBrown You use the operand size override prefix (0x66).

Comment: Isnt 0x66 for 16-bit versions? For CMPSB its either 32 or 64 bit addresses so shouldnt it default to 64bit and then have 0x67 for 32bit addresses?

Comment: @RyanBrown sorry, I've misread your qcomment. I thought you were talking about `cmps` with `qwords`. Of couse, you're right. You need to use `0x67`.